# What's the difference between Objects.requireNonNullElse() and Optional.ofNullable().orElse()?

Tags: java, null, option-type, nullable, java-9

Java 9 introduces the `requireNonNullElse` and `requireNonNullElseGet` methods to the `Objects` class. Are these functionally any different to the `Optional.ofNullable()` `orElse()` and `orElseGet()` methods?

```
String foo = null;
Objects.requireNonNullElse(foo, "nonNull");//returns the string "nonNull"
Optional.ofNullable(foo).orElse("nonNull");//also returns the string "nonNull"
```

If they have no functional difference, why was the `Objects` one added now?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is one minor difference in their behavior. `Objects.requireNonNullElse()` requires that one of the parameters be non-null, otherwise, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

```
String foo = null, bar = null;
Optional.ofNullable(foo).orElse(bar); //returns a null value
Objects.requireNonNullElse(foo, bar); //throws a NullPointerException
```

Comment: There is also the minor non-functional difference that the `Optional` version generates garbage *(unless JIT is smart enough to optimize that away)*.

Comment: @Andreas JMH reports there is no allocation difference between `Optional.ofNullable().orElse()` and `Objects.requireNonNullElse()`

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Only if `foo` is `null`, in which case `ofNullable()` returns the constant *empty* instance. Did you try JMH with a non-null `foo`? Because I took the question as asking what the functional difference is between the two for *any* value, not just the `null` value.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I used non-null `foo`. The allocation rate drops to zero when the method is hot.

Answer (score 5):

The conceptual difference between choosing one over another is as explained in their documentation. It relies on the approach of an API consumer to choose which one of them is supposed to be used effectively by them.

**[`Optional`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)** is container object which may or may not contain a non-null value.

> **A variable whose type is `Optional` should never itself be `null`; it
>   should always point to an `Optional` instance.**
>
> This is a value-based class; use of identity-sensitive operations
>   (including reference equality (==), identity hash code, or
>   synchronization) on instances of Optional may have unpredictable
>   results and should be avoided.

- **[`ofNullable`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-)**

  returns an `Optional` with a present value if the specified value is non-null, otherwise an *empty `Optional`*
- **[`orElse`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-)**

  returns the value if present ***otherwise, returns other***.

Hence the following behaviour:

```
String foo = null;
=> Optional.ofNullable(foo).orElse("nonNull")
=> Optional.ofNullable(null).orElse("nonNull")
=> Optional.empty().orElse("nonNull")
=> return otherwise "nonNull"
```

same as it traverses

```
String foo = null, bar = null;
=> Optional.ofNullable(foo).orElse(bar);
=> Optional.ofNullable(null).orElse(bar);
=> Optional.empty().orElse(bar)
=> return otherwise 'bar'
=> returns null
```

---

**[`Objects`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)**
 **is a class consists of static utility methods for operating on
 objects, or checking certain conditions before an operation.**

> *These utilities include null-safe or null-tolerant methods* for
>   computing the hash code of an object, returning a string for an
>   object, comparing two objects, and checking if indexes or sub-range
>   values are out-of-bounds.

- **[`requireNonNullElse`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-)**

  returns the first argument if ***it is non-null and otherwise*** the second argument ***if it is non-null***

Hence the difference in behaviour:

```
String foo = null;
=> Objects.requireNonNullElse(foo, "nonNull")
=> Objects.requireNonNullElse(null, "nonNull");
```

which further evaluates internally if `requireNonNull("nonNull", "defaultObj")` and then

```
=> returns "nonNull" since its a non-null value
```

now as it traverses

```
String foo = null, bar = null;
=> Objects.requireNonNullElse(foo, bar);
=> Objects.requireNonNullElse(null, bar);
```

It checks internally if `requireNonNull(bar, "defaultObj")` which then

```
=> throws a NullPointerException
```

As documented as well

> `throws NullPointerException` - if both obj is `null` **and** defaultObj
>   is `null`